# how to make haproxy to pass https request to backend server?

Tags: apache, tomcat6, tomcat7, haproxy, stunnel

I have used  HAproxy for load balancing and used Stunnel for SSL .
I have used tomcat as container(backend server) .
In my configuration Stunnel + HAproxy is on one machine (ubuntu 12.04 ) and tomcat is on other machine.
The web application which is deploy on a tomcat use only HTTPS request for login page.
When i try to login using HTTPS request the Stunnel which listen on port 443 decrypt the request and forward to the HAproxy and HAproxy pass it to the Tomcat which is in HTTP format.
As my tomcat configuration request for login page must be in HTTPS format,  my tomcat redirect the request and ask to make same request in HTTPS format.
In this case endless loop created .....

How to configure HAproxy or Stunnel to  pass  HTTPS request to Tomcat......

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at haproxy 1.5-dev12, it offers SSL on both sides and you don't need stunnel anymore.